# c++: subprocess output to stdin

Tags: c++, redirect, stdout, stdin

Suppose I want to call a subprocess from within my program, and I want to read the output from that subprocess into my program.

Here is a trivial way to do that:

```
//somefile.cpp
system("sub_process arg1 arg2 -o file.out");
           //call the subprocess and have it write to file
FILE *f = std::fopen("file.out", "r");
//.... and so on
```

We all know that i/o operations are computationally slow.  To speed this up, I would like to skip the write-to-file-then-read-from-file step, and instead redirect the output of this sub-process *directly into **stdin*** (or some other stream)

How would I do this?  How do I skip the i/o operation?

Note: many programs spit out some diagnostic stuff into stdout while they run, and write a clean version of the output to stdout (ex: stdout: "step1...done, step2...done, step3..done"        -o file-out: "The magic number is: 47.28"), so ignoring the "-o " argument and trusting that output will be automatically re-directed to stdout isn't necessarily helpful...

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Regarding your comment about -o and what happens there - most programs will have a strict definition of what they will output, which your program can filter.

Comment: +CycoMatto, Did you mean "some diagnostic stuff into **stderr** while they run, and write a clean version of the output to **stdout**." Consider a program that outputs some output to '-o file', some output to **stdout**, and some output to **stderr**. Which of those three do you wish to have access to?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Yeah, this was my crucial misunderstanding.  Thanks for the clarification!  See my response to dasblinkenlight below..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `popen` skips the file, and gets you command's output through an in-memory buffer.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_BUFFER = 255;
int main() {
    string stdout;
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
    FILE *stream = popen("command", "r");
    while ( fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER, stream) != NULL )
        stdout.append(buffer);
    pclose(stream);
    cout << endl << "output: " << endl << stdout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the output is quite large, and will take up much more than 255 bytes. +CycoMatto , can you clarify how large you expect this output to be?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid that's OK - the program will read the output in 256-byte increments. If that turns out to be a performance issue, one can always change the size of the buffer. I prefer starting small, and act when the profiler tells me it's a bottleneck.

Comment: But as I mentioned, the command's output will include diagnostic garbage, won't it?   I am looking for the lean, clean stuff written to file  via the -o command.  i.e, I would like to do "-o stdin"

Comment: @CycoMatto You will get only what goes out to stdout, none of the "debugging junk" that's normally sent to stderr. You see the two mixed, because they go to the same console, but internally they are separate streams. If the process that you are planning to run sends "stray output" to `stdout`, you will have to filter it yourself. But most UNIX programs are good players in this regard, so I think you should give it a try.

Comment: +CycoMatto, that is possible. Bear with me while I try to write it up properly. `mkfifo` is your friend.  (Update: I'll wait a moment, I want more clarify, see my comment on the question)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  Aaah, yes that is my misunderstanding.  I overlooked the fact that stderr and stdout are both displayed in the same console.  I suppose I assumed that everybody was irresponsible like I am and wrote everything to `stdout`.  I will correct my etiquette immediately ;).  Thank you!

Comment: I've often thought that the shell/terminal/whatever should find a way to colorize the stderr, precisely so that this confusion won't happen.

Comment: any idea what the namespace of `popen` and `pclose` are?  They are not in namespace `std` , although supposedly they come from `stdio`...

Comment: @CycoMatto `popen` is a system call of UNIX, not a C/C++ library function. That is why it is not part of a namespace.

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to be on windows :

follow this : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351

It describes it better than I ever would. You can redirect everything, everywhere.